# Why my request works with postman but not with vue.js axios?

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios

I've made a back using Flask, and a front using vue.js,

Why I make the request with postman it returns what I want but not with axios ...

for exemple :

```
    this.$axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getUserDataByMail', { mail: 'test@test.com' })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('this.userData')
        console.log(response.data)
        this.userData = response
        }
      )
```

Is treated by :

```
@app.route('/getUserDataByMail', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def getUserDataByMail():
    args = request.args
    mail = args['mail']
    return jsonify(mail)
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    dataCur = cur.execute('select * from userdata where email like "' + mail + '"')
    if dataCur > 0:
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return jsonify(data)
    cur.close()
```

But this result in an error 400 ...

> POSThttp://127.0.0.1:5000/getUserDataByMail [HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST 4ms]
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Help me I'm losing my mind ! (:

Comment: have you configured CORS for your flask project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios by default posts an `application/json` request body.

To read JSON payloads in Flask, you use [`request.json`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.json.JSONMixin.json)

```py
content = request.json
mail = content["mail"]
```

---

I can only assume Postman works because you were posting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body or using URL query parameters.

To match what you're doing in Axios, make sure you post JSON

[image: postman]